# _.map rendering n times for each element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, underscore.js

I have 4 projects that I want to demonstrate on my portfolio website through use of `_.map`. I keep the name, position, start date, end date, etc. in a JSON object and am accessing it through `state`. I have the idea of having n buttons (where n = 4, number of projects I have) and for each modal, have their respective name, dates, etc. be rendered.

```
template(x) {
    console.log(x) # This is mapped properly - each individual project name is rendered
    <div key={x.id}>
        <Button className="modal-button" bsStyle="primary" bsSize="large" onClick={this.openModal.bind(this)}>{x.name}</Button>
        <Modal show={this.state.open} onHide={this.closeModal.bind(this)}>
            <Modal.Body>
                # Right around here, all 4 modals (of each project) is showing up...I'm getting 4 different modals for each button that I click?
                <h4>{x.name}</h4>
                <p>{x.description}</p>
            </Modal.Body>           
        </Modal>
    </div>
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="container-fluid">
            <div className="row">
                {_(this.props.data.work).map((x) => this.template(x))}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Your `template` function returns nothing. It barely can render anything.

Comment: `show={this.state.open}` --- this expression evaluates to the same value for every `x`.

Comment: Is there a better approach I can take? And as for `show`, how can I get it to evaluate to different values?

Comment: Every `x` should have its own set of all properties: `name`, `description` and `open`. Or if you prefer `this.state` - you need to remember what `x` is to be shown (using any kind of identifier you have).

Comment: Kind of confused on how I can keep track of which `x` gets shown. If you can put an example, that'd be great.

Comment: Well, how do you distinguish between them? If you asked to point to one of them manually how would you do that?

Comment: I'm keeping track of them through `id`.

Comment: So, here you go: you can store the `id` of the `x` that is shown, if any. Then your `show` attribute would look like `show={this.state.shownX === x.id}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122563/discussion-between-homerboy-and-zerkms).